# How to detect creation of folders/copying of files created by user/explorer.exe?

Tags: c#, c, windows, winapi, explorer

How to detect creation of folders/copying of files created by user/explorer.exe?
Preferably in C# or VB.NET, but C is fine.
(Note I want folders created by end users, not by Windows/applications)

I found this sample app which made use of SHChangeNotifyRegister:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940348(v=vs.85).aspx

but after testing it I found out that it doesn't just detect files/folders created by the end user, but also by applications (e.g. when hitting "Save" in Excel)

Is it because its detection scope is the "Explorer namespace"? Is it possible to change the sample app to detect the creation of files and folders only those initiated by the end user who is using the explorer shell?

Comment: Explorer is an application. It creates files and folders on behalf of the user in the same way any other application creates files and folders. There is no magic *"initiated by a user"* flag.

Comment: ok, you can just treat my question asking Explorer.exe only, without the "End User" condition

Comment: Have you tried `fSources=SHCNRF_ShellLevel`? That seems like it would provide only notifications coming from explorer.exe (a.k.a. "the shell")